# Eclipse java inherited methods and fields

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, field

Is possible see all methods, fields of class or interface at once in subclass?
Like in maven where possible to see effective maven that includes all included pom files?
May be need some plugin?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you open a Java file and press Ctrl+O inside the editor it will show you all fields and methods of the given class, if you press Ctrl+O once again it will additionally show all inherited methods and fields.